# How do I merge two rows with the same value but keep all the other column data for both in Excel?

Tags: excel

This should be pretty simple I think.

In Excel I've got a list of data I'm gathering from various sources:

| name | time 1 | time 2 | time 3 | Time 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jimmy | 00:30 | 1:30 |  |  |
| john | 01:09 | 1:45 |  |  |
| bobby | 01:09 | 2:49 |  |  |
| elaine | 00:39 | 1:19 |  |  |
| greg | 01:09 | 1:45 |  |  |
| jimmy |  |  | 0:33 | 1:29 |
| bobby |  |  | 0:45 | 1:15 |
| elaine |  |  | 1:24 | 2:01 |
| jack |  |  | 0:10 | 0:50 |

Desired result:

| name | time 1 | time 2 | time 3 | Time 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jimmy | 00:30 | 1:30 | 0:33 | 1:29 |
| john | 01:09 | 1:45 |  |  |
| bobby | 01:09 | 2:49 | 0:45 | 1:15 |
| elaine | 00:39 | 1:19 | 1:24 | 2:01 |
| greg | 01:09 | 1:45 |  |  |
| jack |  |  | 0:10 | 0:50 |

I'm either not knowing the proper way to search for this or something because my normally pretty good google-fu is failing me today.

Edit to clarify:

| name | time 1 | time 2 | time 3 | Time 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jimmy | Burger | HotDog |  |  |
| john | Salami | Samosa |  |  |
| bobby | Burger | Paella |  |  |
| elaine | Sorbet | Muffin |  |  |
| greg | HotDog | Wonton |  |  |
| jimmy |  |  | Tamale | Waffle |
| bobby |  |  | Paella | Tamale |
| elaine |  |  | Waffle | Toffee |
| jack |  |  | Quinoa | Kiwano |

| name | time 1 | time 2 | time 3 | Time 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jimmy | Burger | HotDog | Tamale | Waffle |
| john | Salami | Samosa |  |  |
| bobby | Burger | Paella | Paella | Tamale |
| elaine | Sorbet | Muffin | Waffle | Toffee |
| greg | HotDog | Wonton |  |  |
| jack |  |  | Quinoa | Kiwano |

Rollback

Comment: Which version of excel do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have ***Excel-365*** then use below formulas.

<kbd>G2</kbd> cell `=UNIQUE(A2:A10)` 
<kbd>H2</kbd> cell `=@FILTER(B$2:B$10,($A$2:$A$10=$G2)*(B$2:B$10<>""),"")`

Drag down and across `H2` cell formula as needed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use sumifs formula.

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,$A:$A,$K2)
```

for example,

1. i have kept the unique names in the K column
2. use sumifs formula for B , C , D , E column
3. change the format of the cells to time

Comment: so i put this in column B: `=SUMIFS(B:B,$A:$A,$M2)` and it seems to only have served to put 0 in column B.

Understand, not all of my columns have a time, and im not trying to total the times. I'm only trying to consolidate the rows. I dont want to tally total time, i want to consolidate the records